# Wordpress: automatically add product information into contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm currently building a Wordpress with contact form 7 in it.
The site consists of products that users can ask information about via the contact form. Our problem right now is however, that the user always has to type in the product he wants extra information about into the contact form.
We were wondering whether it's possible to automatically add information into the contact form (like the product name) when the user has clicked on the button 'ask information' that redirected him to the contact form.

Thank you in advance,

J.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, if you can output the information you want (product name) to the page, then do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var product = {"name":"<?php echo $productName; ?>"};
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Then, you should be able to access 'product' within your javascript (obviously doing some sanity checking to make sure it exists etc.)

...and then, it's a bit of a bodge but simply doing something like this:

```
$('#yourInputFieldHere').val(product.name);
```

This has the benefit of a.) not having to have them select a product from a drop down by having it automatically selected for them on page load and b.) no need for manual updating of a list from within CF7

Here's a very quick and dirty jsfiddle to show you how you can get at that information:

https://jsfiddle.net/efreeman79/bhb9b3hr/

edit: Oddly enough, I've had to do this recently but I needed the information in a hidden field, lo and behold there's a plugin to add hidden fields to your contact form 7 forms which can automatically populate itself with the post title / post url etc. - which should be more than enough to satisfy the requirements here:

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. Inside your contact form use a short code, which will get your product name/ID. Or else make a dropdown of products in the contact 7 form.